# Recaptcha no longer working since changing php version

Tags: php, forms, captcha

I have a contact form made in php which was sending fine until i changed the php version for the wordpress part of my website and now the contact form wont work with the captcha.

The form was sending the contact form to the email but once the php version has changed when the form is filled in it returns this "Please check the the captcha form"

If i change the php version back it works fine but then the wordpress wont work. Any Ideas?

```
  <?php

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        // access
        $secretKey = '6LeLKR8eAAAAAKs2E8ldKBQwfkUtiFyoozKMswhd';
        $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

        if(!$captcha){
          echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">Please check the the captcha form.</p>';
          exit;
        }

        # FIX: Replace this email with recipient email
        $mail_to = "EMAIL@EMAIL.COM";

        # Sender Data
        $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," ") , strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"])));
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        if ( empty($name) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) OR empty($phone) OR empty($message)) {
            # Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">Please complete the form and try again.</p>';
            exit;
        }

        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
        $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);

        if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
          echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">Please check the the captcha form.</p>';
        } else {
            
            $subject = 'Enquiry From Website ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            # Mail Content
            $content = "Name: $name\n";
            $content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
            $content .= "Phone: $phone\n";
            $content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

            # email headers.
            $headers = "From: $name <$email>";

            # Send the email.
            $success = mail($mail_to, $subject, $content, $headers);
            header('Location: thank-you');
            if ($success) {
header('Location: thank-you');
            } else {
                # Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
                http_response_code(500);
                echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">Oops! Something went wrong, we couldnt send your message.</p>';
            }
        }

    } else {
        # Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">There was a problem with your submission, please try again.</p>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: _"not working"_ isn't an error description and doesn't give us anything to go on. Please edit your question and give us a detailed explanation of your issue. What happens? Errors? White page? What debugging have you done? Checked the error log?

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to help without seeing the errors. If you yourself don't see them then enable with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

A blind shot: Check php.ini parameter `allow_url_include` - is it enabled?

If not, it would produce this error:
`https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0`